# Middleware presence couldn't block request from hitting the routes

Tags: python, django, middleware, django-middleware

I have written the middleware for Session Management, What I observe is that the Middleware is working fine up to the expectations when it comes to redirection to the desired page as per the session state.

But the problem is that the routes which I have written only to be hit when the session is active, are still getting hit irrespective of session state even after the redirection.

E.g: The secure home route should only be accessible when the session is set, Middleware doing their job by redirecting the page to Login, But In the server, I can see the Home route was still hit

I could write again the block of code like

```
if sessionActive:
  // Code Goes Here Which Should Run For Active Session State
else:
  // Return with Forbidden Message
```

I'm assuming Why should I write above piece of code when the middleware is in place?

**PFB, the code of Middleware:**

```
# Middleware Class to Handle Session & JWT default operations
# Written By: XXXX
# Date Written: Jan 1, 2019

from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from libraries.PostgreSQLConnector import PostgreSQLConnector
import jwt


class SessionHandler( object ):

  '''
  Main Function to process request header authenticity
  Params: Object <request>
  Return Type: Object
  '''
  def process_request( self, request ):
    response = self.get_response( request )
    path = request.path_info
    PUBLIC_URLS = ('/authme/',)
    if path in PUBLIC_URLS:
      return response
    else:
      return self.regressChecking( request, path )

  def regressChecking( self, request, path ):
    response  = self.get_response( request )
    stoken = request.session.get('token', False)
    if 'ctoken' in request.COOKIES and stoken:
      if request.COOKIES['ctoken'] == stoken:
        if not path.startswith("/admin") and request.method != 'POST':
          return self.validatePagePermission( request, stoken, path )
        return response
    else:
        response_redirect = HttpResponseRedirect('/authme/')
        response_redirect.delete_cookie('csrftoken')
        response_redirect.delete_cookie('ctoken')
        return response_redirect


  def validatePagePermission( self, request, token, path ):
    if request.method == "GET":
      token_dump = jwt.decode( token , "SECRET", algorithms="HS256")
      userID = token_dump['user_id']
      status = self.validateUserPerm( path, userID )
      if status:
        return self.get_response( request )
      return HttpResponse("You are not allowed to access this page")


  def validateUserPerm( self, SLUG, USERID ):
    psy = PostgreSQLConnector( )
    QUERY = '''select count(id) as is_present from system_user_form_level_permission where form_id_fk_id IN
     (select id from system_app_form where form_name_html LIKE '%s') AND app_assignment_id_fk_id IN
     (select id from system_apps_assignment where user_id_fk_id = %d )''' % ( SLUG, USERID )
    r = psy._custom( QUERY , "select")
    if len(r['data']) != 0:
      return True
    return False

  def __init__( self, get_response ):
    self.get_response = get_response

  def __call__(self, request):
    response =  self.process_request(request)
    return response
```

Please suggest if any lack in the middleware? Or Do we still need to explicitly insert the code of session check before the secure code begins?

Comment: Please check what your query is returning inside *validateUserPerm* function. Or you can check your middleware by explicitly returning false in *validateUserPerm* function.

Comment: They are working fine

Answer (score 0):

`get_response` calls the downstream code, ie the URLs and views. You should organise move call inside your if block.

Comment: I didn't understand. Do you mean I have to put if-session active in each call? Can you share any reference URL, Please?